# PHPExcel setWidth();

Tags: symfony, width, phpexcel

Hi i'm using PhpExcel and Symfony2 , displaying excel files in HTML table.

My controller :

```
    $filterSubset = new \PHPExcel_Reader_DefaultReadFilter('A','N');
    $objReader = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($excel[0]);
    $objReader->setReadFilter($filterSubset);
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($excel[0]);
    $writer = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, "HTML");
    $writer->generateStyles();
    $writer->generateSheetData();

    return $this->render('MonextPerfclientBundle:Default:testexcel.html.twig', array(
        'excelHtml'=>$writer,
        'stylesExcel'=>$writer,
```

My ReadFilter class :

```
class PHPExcel_Reader_DefaultReadFilter implements PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter
{

   public function __construct($fromColumn, $toColumn) {
       $this->columns = array();
       $toColumn++;
       while ($fromColumn !== $toColumn) {
           $this->columns[] = $fromColumn++;
       }
   }

public function readCell($column, $row, $worksheetName = '') {
    // Read columns from 'A' to 'N'
    if (in_array($column, $this->columns)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

How can i set width of the 'E' column ?

Blanks columns still displaying..dont know why..

Why the width of columns are always different ?

Thanks @MarkBaker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To manage the width of columns cell you should setting the width in the controller.

   .

   ```
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('E')->setWidth(40);
   ```
2. Blanks columns still displaying: You should manage the empty columns from the writer
3. The width of the olumns is depending on the length of data contained in first line.

Comment: How can i manage the empty columns from the writer ? I dont understand

Comment: What is the max width ? it doesnt change anything if i try setWidth(100); for example..

Comment: where do i put this line of code please ? @MohamedBenHENDA

Comment: @Simon Delaunay In your controller before " $writer = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, "HTML"); "